# spin projector in inverted matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, physics, inverse

The following matrix $A$ is,
\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b-\sigma\cdot \textbf p & -x_1 \\
x_2 & a-b-\sigma\cdot \textbf p
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The inversion of matrix $A$ is, 
\begin{equation}
A^{-1}=
\frac{\begin{bmatrix}
a-b-\sigma\cdot \textbf p & x_1 \\
-x_2 & a+b-\sigma\cdot \textbf p
\end{bmatrix}}{a^2-b^2+p^2-2\sigma\cdot \textbf p-x_1x_2}
\end{equation}
However, p.4 equation (31) of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0631.pdf) where matrix $A$ is taken from shows the formula in different form,
\begin{equation}
A^{-1}=
\frac{0.5\begin{bmatrix}
(\sigma_o+\sigma\cdot \hat{\textbf p})(a-b+p) & (\sigma_o+\sigma\cdot \hat{\textbf p}) x_1 \\
-x_2(\sigma_o+\sigma\cdot \hat{\textbf p}) & \sigma_y(\sigma_o+\sigma\cdot \hat{\textbf p})\sigma_y(a+b-p)
\end{bmatrix}}{a^2-b^2-p^2+2bp-x_1x_2}
\end{equation}
and $\hat{p}=\frac{p}{b}$ and $\sigma$'s are 2x2 pauli matrices such that $\sigma\sigma=1$.  The $\sigma$s inside brackets are projectors.  How it is derived?  How projector is used to get the inversion of matrix $A$ that looks different from conventional method used to calculate $A^{-1}$? What kind of algebra it is using to get this?

Comment: $a$,$b$,$p$,$x_1$,$x_2$ are any real numbers/scalars. The $\cdot$ means vector dot product.  All $\sigma$'s are Pauli 2x2 matrices.

Comment: @Aschoolar I don't understand. If $a, b, p$ are scalars, $\sigma$ is a $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrix and $(\cdot)$ is the dot product, then what does $a + b - \sigma \cdot p$ mean? How can you dot-multiple a matrix to a scalar and then add it to a scalar?

Comment: @user1551, I corrected equation.  Dotted p should be a vector so I emphasized it with bold text or bold p. $a$ and $b$  and $p$ (unbold) are constants

Comment: @Aschoolar There is still an issue. In the matrix $A$, no unbold $p$ occurs, but in the matrix $A^{-1}$, an unbold $p$ occurs in $p^2$. Can you clarify what's going on?

Comment: Could you tell us the title of your textbook?

Comment: Its not a textbook.  It is an article.  I believe the author used a form of algebra I am not familiar with such as mulitplication of the matrix by some projection vector or some form of substitution equivalent.    Pg 4 equation (31) https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0631